# DSE Cassandra audit log not capturing UDTs in DML

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.0, datastax-java-driver

I have setup DSE Cassandra audit log feature on a particular keyspace. By referring below documentation -

https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/5.0/datastax_enterprise/sec/auditConfigCassandraTable.html

This is working perfectly fine. But, The problem is the DML statement that is captured in the column "operation" has bind variables for prepared statement. This is executed using DSE Driver through a java program. For UDTs this bind variable is captured as some hexadecimal value.

for ex: opts=000000120000002f00000003414c4c000000045253434800000001590000000800000162e0e658180000000641504952414d00000001490000002f0000000

I need to know how to parse this hexadecimal value to get actual data.

Comment: We updated to dse 6.0.4 and Still this issue persists. 

Its a known issue with dse cassandra audit log feature and not addressed due to performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a problem with specific version of DSE. I just tested with 5.1 & 6.0, and in both of them the data is reported correctly (I've used the mapper to generate queries):

```
INFO  [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2018-08-20 08:53:48,754  SLF4JAuditWriter.java:96 - host:localhost/127.0.0.1|source:/127.0.0.1|user:anonymous|authenticated:anonymous|timestamp:1534748028754|category:DML|type:CQL_PREPARE_STATEMENT|ks:test|cf:audit_test|operation:INSERT INTO test.audit_test (id,u) VALUES (?,?);
INFO  [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2018-08-20 08:53:48,770  SLF4JAuditWriter.java:96 - host:localhost/127.0.0.1|source:/127.0.0.1|user:anonymous|authenticated:anonymous|timestamp:1534748028770|category:DML|type:CQL_UPDATE|ks:test|cf:audit_test|operation:INSERT INTO test.audit_test (id,u) VALUES (?,?); [id=2,u=2:test 2]|consistency level:LOCAL_ONE
```

Consider upgrade to the 5.1 at least...

P.S. Just found that in the 5.1, the output of sets doesn't work (maybe with other collections as well).